# NSObject incrementing a Pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

Is that possible to increment  NSObject by using (*name)++?
If it's an int for example you can Increment  by using

```
int *i; (*i)++;
```

But if it is  NSObject, how we can increment the pointer?

```
myClass* p1=array[0];
myClass* p2=array[10];
MyClass* temp=p1;
(*p1)++; //Here an error happen
```

Comment: Isn't your statement effectively `MyClass++`?

Comment: Why are you trying to increment the object? Your code does not increment the pointer, but tries to increment the object. That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
int *i; (*i)++;
```

works because `i` is an pointer to in `int`. `(*i)++` means get the object that `i` points to (which is an `int`) and increment it. As you can increment an int, this works.

Now for the rest of your question:

```
myClass* p1=array[0];
```

means `p1` is an pointer to a `myClass` object

and:

```
(*p1)++;
```

means get the object at that `p1` points to (which is a `myClass` instance) and increment it. However, it doesn't make sense to increment an object; so this isn't going to work.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can increment object types like that as the compiler wouldnt know ***How*** to increment the object. But you can absolutely do it with primitive types such as int and float.

**However**: You Can implement a for loop to increment a property on your object multiple times or 
use an operator like `+=` to increment once. Once again this can only be done on primitive types.